# В защиту открытости

Tags: обсуждение

Думая, стоит или не стоит закрыть слишком для нас простой вопрос от слишком ленивого автора, полезно принять во внимание к чему политика удаления не достаточно энциклопедических статей привела в Википедии: [In Defense Of Inclusionism](https://www.gwern.net/In-Defense-Of-Inclusionism):

> English Wikipedia is in decline. As a long-time editor & former admin,
>   I was deeply dismayed by the process. Here, I discuss UI principles,
>   changes in Wikipedian culture, the large-scale statistical evidence of
>   decline, run small-scale experiments demonstrating the harm, and
>   conclude with parting thoughts.

(предупреждение: статья длинная, содержит цифры и ссылки на исследования).

Comment: `created: 15 Jan 2009; modified: 06 Dec 2016; status: finished; belief: highly likely` -- 7 лет, надо же...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletionism_and_inclusionism_in_Wikipedia

Comment: @NickVolynkin, еще одна длинная статья. А у Вас какое резюме по ней?

Comment: @avp пока без резюме, но есть материал чтобы подумать.

Comment: @jfs вы только что сами участвовали в закрытии темы только потому, что ответом на него не была ссылка на ваш ответ, данный в другом месте. И даже не поинтересовались у постера, помог ли ему хоть один из ответов.. Это, простите, лицемерие. Я про тему "Как изменить locale.getpreferredencoding() кодировку US-ASCII на UTF-8 в Python 3.x? " И даже пространно рассуждаете ни о чем, как в этой теме "Определить количество строк в строковой переменной", но закрываете других за подобное.

Comment: @dio4: странный комментарий 1- возможность закрытия вопросов как дубликатов является полезной функциональностью вообще и закрытие [примера, который вы указали,](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/603509/23044) является оправданным в частности (автор вопроса нашёл предоставленную ссылку полезной) 2-  я вижу упоминание конкретных фактов ("universal newlines"), рабочий код (`wc_line_count()`, `line_count()`) в [моём комментарии](https://goo.gl/OZIyqM). Я искренне не понимаю как это можно охарактеризовать как  *"пространно рассуждаете ни о чем"*

Comment: уверен, вы меня отлично поняли.

Comment: @dio4: факты: Вы забыли упомянуть, что вы не объективный наблюдатель, а вы автор ответа на вопрос, который я  закрыл как дубликат. Вы забыли упомянуть, что у вашего ответа три минуса (у нормальных ответов такого практически нет). Вы забыли упомянуть, что вы удалили свой ответ. Теперь становится ясным контекст для тона ваших комментариев и нежелания понимать технические доводы.