# Бан модератора (♦)

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, блокировка

Недавно [избранный народом модератор](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) получил бан.
Хотелось бы получить официальный ответ о причинах и стоит ли нам делать перевыборы?

Comment: Да! Стоит выбрать @Grundy Наконец :)

Comment: @Grundy, подождите, Вашу пиар-акцию ещё рано проводить, может ещё обойдётся :)

Comment: Показательно, мол даже админ может получить бан, если будет плохо себя вести) Но плюсую @Grundy =)))

Comment: @HamSter, его же выперли из модеров чата, а его синдром политоты ещё агонизирует!

Comment: Народных избранников щемят! 
А если серьезно, то думаю стоило бы под блокировкой писать причину

Comment: Не был согласен с генеральной линией партии

Comment: Мне кажется мета должна модерироваться так (бан модера) в крайнем случаи. Высказывание @Qwerty хоть и не очень сдержанное было, но явно заслуживало больше чем просто удаление комментариев и бан. Надо искать компромисс, чтоб всем было хорошо ) (про Grundy я вообще удивлен что он не стал модератором.. тогдаб все вопросы про JS летели бы  в дубликат по ассинхронщине )) )

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich, а весь чат - в политоту.

Comment: кстати, только что узнал что нельзя двух людей упоминать в одном комментарии сразу (ничего себе)))  (@). Извини Grundy пришлось тобой пожертвовать )

Comment: @Other, вот этой информацией, извиняюсь, я не обладаю. В чат захожу не часто, и не вижу связи моего  комментария с политикой. Но если что, то "политоту" (как вы выразились) конечно надо банить и карать.

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich, забейте, камерная шуточка.

Comment: @Alexander Igorevich "явно заслуживало больше чем просто удаление комментариев и бан" больше чем бан? что вы имеете ввиду - пожизненный бан ?только за то, что высказал непопулярное мнение?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Вы не так поняли мой комментарий. Я имею ввиду наоборот, принять во внимание его высказывание и дать возможность всем высказаться, кто и что думает. (_...но явно заслуживало больше чем.._)

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich спасибо, понял

Comment: Предложил бы не зафлуживать тему. Ситуация достаточно серьёзная. Спасибо.

Comment: @RTK причина пишется в профиле на основном сайте

Comment: @PashaPash, да я Вас умоляю, Изя, там стандартная отмазка.

Comment: Будь моя воля, я бы всех модераторов перебанил и подарил бы наконец людям свободное общение, с понями и гомониграми.

Comment: @Diskyp вы у нас чьим клоном будете ? :-)

Comment: @Foggy Finder я секретный эксперемет по клонированию Чака Норриса, так что лучше со мной соглашаться, иначе могу отправить лоукик по оптоволокну.

Comment: @Diskyp: Пони и гомонигры выдают :)

Comment: @VladD, гомокто? Богатый опыт... хм... кино даёт странную картину.

Comment: @Suvitruf, на чужой роток не набросишь платок!

Comment: @Suvitruf, Вряд ли. Я не против него, просто у чувака нервы сдали. Бывает, чо!

Comment: @Suvitruf, это да. Но не напишу почему, а то опять в бан улечу уже на основных сайтах.

Comment: Вот это новость похлеще блокировки телеграмма!

Comment: @alexolut, это ещё что, уже комнату успели заморозить от накала, а Вы всё пропустили :)

Comment: **Аналогия** В Русской Википедии есть механизм против подобного рода блокировок. Если администратора оскорбил (по мнению оскорблённого) не очевидный вандал, а участник с большим положительным вкладом, то крайне не рекомендуется самостоятельно блокировать оскорбившего участника. Решение относительно наказания оскорбившего должен принимать другой администратор. Причина — оскорбления в свой адрес воспринимаются иначе, повышена вероятность не основанного на правилах решения. Неплохо было бы похожее правило принять. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, но у нас тут дикта... один админ.

Comment: @Other, **1.** Надо было мне пояснить нестыковку в терминах: *модератор Stack Overflow* = по функциям *администратор Википедии*. // **2.** На RuSO помимо Qwertiy и Nicolas Chabanovskiy есть 4 человека, имеющих техническую возможность блокировки. Любой из них может принять решение относительно наказания оскорбившего. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, Вы уравниваете их, тогда как у Николаса гораздо большие возможности. Поэтому неправильно так судить, да и, возможно, у простого модератора нет права забанить себеподобного.

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи, затронутые в этом конфликте! Призываю Вас взять внеплановый отпуск на пару месяцев - чтобы остудить голову и показать что будет с сообществом, без старичков. А потом посмотрим как будет идти рассуждение о полезности. Сам получил бан в чате за [абсолютно нейтральное сообщение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhxeF.png), поэтому покидаю SO на неопределённое время. Не хочу находится в обществе с таким управлением, которое мы имеем на данный момент. Надеюсь, Вы успеете прочитать это до удаления этого сообщения. Спасибо, было приятно с Вами общаться.

Comment: Наконец-то перечитал все(включая комментарии). Скажу, что эмоции тут захлестывают и о принятых тех или иных решениях, будут в последствии жалеть, многие. Предлагаю остыть всем и вернуться к обсуждению этой проблемы через пару дней.

Comment: По моему тут оба модератора перегнули палку. Но ответственность ложится на того, кто главнее. О каком управлении сообществом может идти речь, если управляющий не может навести порядок в модераторском сообществе из 5 человек. И (я так считаю) никакой модератор или администратор не должен принимать какие-то решения по вопросам в которых он является заинтересованной стороной.

Comment: @СашаЧерных не стоит попытаться доверие к конкретным людям (таким как СМ) на бюрократию заменить. Это не спасёт: «закон что дышло, куда повернул туда и вышло» и это препятствует обычным людям конструктивно участвовать на Мете без юридического образования.  Про Википедию познавательно: [В защиту открытости](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4200/23044)

Answer (score 9):

## TL; DR;

Причина бана — необоснованные, грубые, личные обвинения в сторону другого участника вместо попытки решить проблему через обсуждение.

## Полная версия

Чтобы понять причину бана, нужно понимать механизм правил и их применения SO:

- Есть правила, [они полностью изложены в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help). По сути, правила это

  - [требования к вопросам (онтопик / оффтопик)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
  - [требования к ответам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
  - [требования к отношению к другим участникам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)
  - требования ко всему остальному, от комментариев до меток
- Содержимое правил **полностью** задается администрацией (не модераторами, не Николасом, а администрацией на уровне компании).
- Правила одинаково применимы ко всем участникам (от 1-реп до ромбов). Наказание за умышленное нарушение правил для 1, 5к и ромба — одинаковое (+у ромба могут еще и ромб отобрать)
- Результаты голосования на мете за что угодно не являются критерием смены правил, но:
- Администрация (в лице CM) очень старается прислушиваться к результатам голосования. Если до этого момента вы считали, что тут правит демократия, и голосование автоматически приводит к смене правил — значит, CM хорошо справлялся со своими обязанностями.

В рамках именно нашего сайта CM-ом был [предложен механизм инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6835/). Это, по сути, был проблеск демократии в мире SO — сообществу разрешалось напрямую, через голосование, менять правила.

Его как-то не оценили, наверное, потому что и до него хватало прямого принятия решений CM на основе голосования. CM просто хорошо слушал сообщество. И поэтому никто не понял до конца, зачем хитрый механизм обхода CM вообще нужен.

Но даже в рамках инициатив и при очень внимательном и отзывчивом CM есть определенные правила, которые поменять нельзя. Можно расширить онтопик, можно разрешить кодгольф, можно поменять причины закрытия в попытках преследовать халявщиков. Наверное, можно даже разрешить вопросы-опросники.

Но нельзя поменять базовые правила. Нельзя отменить "будьте дружелюбными" и разрешить хамить. Нельзя сменить модель с QA на "разговоры о жизни". Если на уровне компании задано жесткое правило к чистоте вопросов и ответов от приветов и прощаний — значит его нельзя взять и отменить локально.

Как это привело к бану?

- На мете был поднят вопрос о бездействии модераторов в отношении тревог на комментариях-благодарностях: [Отклонены тревоги "более не является необходимым" и другие казусы модерации комментариев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7046/) До этого [уже предлагалось сносить такие комментарии автоматически, и предложение не встретило особого сопротивления](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4468/).
- Да, требования к удалению спасиб есть в правилах. Причем в тех самых, которые спущены сверху. Ну и опять же — сообщество явно за удаление спасиб.  (достаточно просто посмотреть баланс голосов). Лично я — против. Но правила есть правила (см. выше).
- CM оказывается в ситуации когда спасиб много, удалять их надо (народ требует). И он предлагает удаление спасиб автоматизировать: [Автоматическое удаление комментариев по тревоге «более не является необходимым»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7095/)

Да, высказываются вполне обоснованные предупреждения, что под удаление могут попасть не спасибы, а все подряд. Решение CM вполне нейтральное — взять и померять. Включить механизм удаления, и через 2 недели посмотреть на результат.

Ок, проходит две недели, CM отчитывается о результатах: [Две недели с удаления более не нужных комментариев с заданными словами без проверки модераторами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7155/)

Результаты: удалено 50 сообщений, пару ложных срабатываний. Отличный результат для регекса, у модераторов точность ниже! Участники высказываются что 50 — мало, надо хотя бы 1000. 50 — действительно мало, и уточнить регекс по ним нельзя (наверное). Ок, меряем еще две недели.

Через пару дней попавший под ложное срабатывание участник приходит на мету и спрашивает "почему мой коммент удалили".

Ок, я бы ожидал реакции "да, не надо ждать 1000 сообщений, как посоветовало *сообщество*, а стоит поменять регекс на более точный".

Реакция забаненого участника — в грубой форме заявить что CM игнорирует чужие мнения. Не в ответ на слова CM, не в ответ на реальное игнорирование. А просто так.

Если честно, я до сих пор не понимаю причин такого заявления. CM делал ровно то, что от него требовалось, и более того — следовал поддержанному сообщестам совету собрать статистику побольше.

Он сделал выбор между "как захотел Qwertiy" и "как потребовало сообщество" в сторону последнего. Qwertiy, как модератор, должен это прекрасно понимать.

Comment: Последний абзац явно лишний, нет ничего что подтверждало бы это утверждение. Я про оба тезиса (наличие выбора и наличие _требования_ сообщества). Как показывает практика и диалог в чате - сообщество ничего требовать не может. Да и что по-вашему мнению должен делать другой участник уж точно к рассматриваемому вопросу не относиться.

Comment: "Нельзя сменить модель с QA на "разговоры о жизни"." [Можно!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5812/181100) PS: Желающих обсудить эту тему прошу проследовать **туда**, в вопрос.

Comment: @GreenDragon сообщество регулярно что-то требует и CM регулярно на эти требования отзывается. Например, сообщество потребовало ввести причину закрытия "домашние задания". CM было против. Я был против. Сообщество наголосовало - причину ввели. Так что ваше заявление о практике не совсем соотвествует действительности.

Comment: @GreenDragon что, по моему мнению, обязан был делать другой участник, и что не обязан - имеет прямое отношение в вопросу. Вопрос - за что забанили. Его забанили за то, что он сделал одно (а обязан был, как модератор, делать другое).

Comment: @GreenDragon если вы считаете, что у CM не было выбора в такой ситуации - ок, что, по вашему, должен был сделать CM? Отключить регулярку и призвать модераторов удалять спасибы вручную?

Comment: @PashaPash в какой ситуации? Я бы не стал удалять ни один комментарий до завершения разбирательства(если про комментарий со словами Кверти). По поводу авто-удаления комментариев для меня этот вопрос яйца выеденного не стоит, если комментарий потерял актуальность, то его можно удалить, а если нет - значит не нужно, уважайте чужой труд. Но даже если и сносите - напишите об этом и все (это - лично моя точка зрения), желательно сделать авто-уведомление для участников как происходит с выборами, шляпами, etc ... чтобы они знали что писать не имеет смысла т.к. будет удалено.

Comment: @GreenDragon Решение в таких случаях должны принимать или другие модераторы или CM, а не сообщество. Модераторы видят удаленное. Там же другие участники уже начали локально обсуждать поведение и порицать всех подряд,  jfs так вообще жестко высказался (снес в чат, коммент был с +8)  Т.е. разбирательство было, но достаточно недолгое, и не было смысла его затягивать, т.к. там со стороны Кверти было все очень неконструктивно :(. По поводу автоудаления комментариев - согласен, вопрос совершенно минорный, и да - предупреждения нужны (и для ручного удаления тоже)

Comment: Вас интересовало что бы я сделал _будь_ КМ, я не спорю что решение не должно было принимать сообщество ;-) Если бы коммент висел очень недолго - да, снести и решить приватно, но если уж начали публично обвинять, то и отвечать я бы стал публично.

Comment: "CM делал ровно то, что от него требовалось" вы лукавите переходя от частного в общему. Если брать за основу вопрос с авто-удалением, то да, 16/12 это не сильный, но все-же перевес. Но если копнуть глубже был вопрос об удалении спасибок, где перевес на стороне желающих их оставить. Но, в предлагаемом автоудалении слово "спасибо" было включено. Это не игнорирование мнения сообщества?

Comment: "Он сделал выбор между "как захотел Qwertiy" и "как потребовало сообщество" в сторону последнего. " Из предыдущего комментария должно быть очевидно, что ваш тезис мягко говоря далек от истины. То есть сообщество согласилось с авто-удалением (как с механизмом), но не согласилось с регуляркой. Если бы вопросы разделили на 2 (о непосредственном вводе и о том, что должно захватывать регулярка) результаты были бы более объективными.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Так был же вопрос с обсуждением регулярки и с входными данными. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7095/. Там с большим отрывом 16/0 лидирует именно сузить регулярку и удалять именно спасибо :) проблема только в том, что никто не предложил альтернативную регулярку. Я предложил в пм, обсудил с Николасом, он попросил меня опубликовать ее для обсуждения - не хотел выписывать втихаря, без обсуждения с сообществом. А я завяз в работе и не успел :(

Comment: @FoggyFinder т.е. да,  были еще альтернативные вопросы голосовалки от Q. Я не до конца понял их цель. Выразить протест тем,  что у нас спасибо запрещены?  Так они запрещены не Николасом,  а глобально по SO. Если хотите разрешить - надо или через Николаса пробивать исключение (а вопрос слишком минорный и консенсуса нет)  или на метамете продвигать.

Comment: @FoggyFinder собственно, мой ответ выше как раз об этом. Об иерархии правил и о механизмах их изменений. Николас не может сам разрешить спасибо и не пропихнет их разрешение пока у нас за них нет огромного перевеса голосов.

Comment: @PashaPash не увидел отдельного вопроса. То есть об автоматическом удалении сообщество не спрашивали, лишь о регулярке? Выходит я неправильно понял вопрос

Comment: @FoggyFinder да. Т.е. ситуация именно такая - если сообщество заявило, что модераторы не смогут сами удалить спасибо - СМ обязан дернуть рубильник и включить автоудаление. Не будь рубильника - модеры бы сказали "ну ок,  правила есть правила" и начали бы тереть вручную.

Comment: @PashaPash вы допускаете что Qwertiy мог быть введен в заблуждение вопросом от Николаса как и я? Логическую выкладку см. в моих первых комментариях. Тогда действительно (с такой точки зрения) в этом случае КМ пренебрег мнением сообщества и критика была оправдана по содержанию, но не по форме?

Comment: @FoggyFinder есть контент, не соотвествующий требованиям + есть жалобы от участников на его наличие + есть слишком много, руками не удалим + есть готовый механизм = автоудаление регуляркой. [Предложено на мете, поддержано 16/0](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7098/).  "не хотим удаление спасибок"  - это где-то в параллельных обсуждениях. Одни хотят, вторые не хотят, третьи хотят, но не доверяют автоматике. Есть правила уровня SO с "обязаны", CM обязан их придерживаться. Модераторы - тоже.

Comment: @FoggyFinder я могу предполагать что угодно. у модераторов есть отдельный чат с CM. Если это была критика - то она не была оправдана ни по форме, ни по месту, ни по обоснованности.

Comment: @GreenDragon нельзя конструктивно ответить на критику вида "тебе плевать на чужие мнения".  Это не критика, это прямые обвинения. Попытки публичного ответа вида "это клевета, какие ваши доказательства" и привели к тому, что имеем.

Comment: "я могу предполагать что угодно" нет, я о другом, вы написали в сообщении "Если честно, я до сих пор не понимаю причин такого заявления." - я предложил логичное, с моей точки зрения обоснование.

Comment: Можно - во-первых обсудить приватно почему такое сообщение вообще было написано, а во-вторых - вынести отдельным сообщением либо опровержение (с данными), либо пояснение за что конкретно отвечает КМ(объяснить что обвинения не по адресу), либо вопрос где отвечающие могли бы высказать критику в конструктивном ключе. А лучше все сразу. Да, и я не видел попыток публичного ответа, их тоже уже удалили?

Comment: @FoggyFinder если сообщество заявило, что модераторы не смогут сами удалить спасибо - плохо сформулировал. модераторы заявили не смогут сами удалить спасибо из-за количества спасиб на сайте.

Comment: @GreenDragon приватно вроде бы обсудили. опровергнуть данными такое утверждение нельзя (посчитать, сколько раз CM послушал чужое мнение?). К тому же, это обвинение Q уже несколько раз выдвигал, в такой же форме. И тоже без подтверждения, данных и прочих пруфов. Процесс принятия решений и "CM не совсем виноват" - вот, в моем ответе выше.

Comment: ок, допустим с опровержением действительно сложно, да и доказывать надо обвинение. Но что насчет пояснения и предложения про предоставление возможности высказать критику конструктивно?

Comment: @GreenDragon я сейчас вижу конкретную проблему в непрозрачности процессе смены правил, и в том, что многие топовые участники считают, что у нас тут демократия, и что наголосовали - то и правила. Я вот это озвучил (просто констатировал факт) - и появились возмущенные. Насчет предложения возможности высказать критику - у Q есть приватный модераторский чат и возможность высказать там любую критику в любой момент. Есть почта Николаса. Не вижу, почему нужно предоставлять еще какую-то дополнительную возможность, если не было попыток использовать те, что уже есть.

Comment: тогда предлагаю решение - напишите вопрос на мете "Какие именно вопросы решает сообщество". Это будет очень конструктивно. У Q может и есть приватный чат, а у простых участников - только Мета.

Answer (score 3):

Как многим известно, бан был за излишне резкое заявление о менеджере сообщества. Я извиняюсь, что не высказался там более мягко и надеюсь на дальнейшее сотрудничество.

К тому же, у того вопроса этот комментарий был не совсем в тему.

Многие тут считают, что моё заявление было вызвано технической ошибкой в используемой для автоудаления комментариев регулярке и является необоснованной агрессией против того, кто эту систему применил. Я бы хотел отметить, что это не так, и реальной причиной являлось несколько совершенно других (нетехнических) факторов, которые я в данный момент перечислять не хочу.

Comment: Надавили, запугали, запретили, заставили? :)

Comment: @Other, попросили написать побыстрее. Действительно попросили (и, на этот раз, даже не Николас), не заставляли. В принципе, я подобное уже писал в ЛС, а может и в чате даже.

Comment: А что такого? Чтобы всякие там Другие ещё одну тему с жалобами не создали?

Comment: @Other, просто хочу сохранить ромбик.

Comment: Но ведь уже всё обошлось, тема эта, как сказал Николас, вообще не нужна (персон мы не обсуждаем), значит не нужно официально извинятся тут. Причина тогда?

Comment: @Other, ну видимо, ещё нет...

Comment: Считали ли вы, когда делали то заявление, что потребность в той или иной фиче решается *только* сообществом, через голосование на мете?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, если бы я так считал, я бы не делал то заявление. Тем не менее, я считаю, что в некоторый момент это изменилось. Впрочем, вроде к данному вопросу это вообще не относится.

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, в будущем соблюдайте правило: [Следует ли обращаться к участникам по имени в вопросах на Мете?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4790/) — мы хотим улучшить сообщество, подходы и правила модерации, а не устраивать публичные разбирательства. Если вам действительно не ясно конкретное действие в отношении конкретного участника, задайте ваш вопрос по почте (контакты в моем профиле) или через форму обратной связи.

В качестве исключения, все же, рассмотрим вопрос, так как он касается модератора.

---

#### В чем причина блокировки

Участник был заблокирован потому что не соблюдал правило [дружелюбия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Любая блокировка сопровождается письмом от модераторов участнику, в которой пишется причина блокировки и рекомендации о том, чего делать не стоит. Остальные участники видят причину блокировки на странице учетной записи.

#### Критика выбранных подходов на основе данных — конструктивна, личности автора инициативы на основе личного мнения — субъективна

Stack Overflow — это уникальное явление. Создавая что–то новое, невозможно не допускать ошибки. Если бы кто–то точно знал как запускать подобные проекты, сайт не был был лучшим и, по сути, единственный в своем роде. Проекту повезло — участники сообщества невероятно сообразительные и социально активные люди, которым не безразлична судьба их коллег. Вместе мы создаем не только базу знаний, но и инструменты управления сообществом, вводим процессы и правила взаимодействия на сайте, чтобы каждому, кто хочет получить ответ по программированию на прикладной вопрос, на нашем сайте нашлось место.

Сделать все с первого раза — идеализированный подход, который существует только на бумаге.

[image]

Все же, ошибаться хотелось бы как можно реже. Чтобы избежать возможных будущих недочетов, большинство инициатив, даже тех, в пользе которых «компания» уверена на все 100%, мы выносим на рассмотрение сообществу, чтобы услышать вашу критику и, при необходимости, скорректировать план действий. Мы рады и благодарны участникам, за всю предоставленную конструктивную критику! Знайте, без вас, коллеги, у сообщества не было бы столь прекрасного движка для накопления знаний.

Другая сторона выбранного нами подхода к развитию с множеством альтернативных точек зрения на проблему на Мете — [не все они будут воплощены в жизнь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/6) и авторы предложений могут остаться недовольны, что компания сделала не так как «как ей сказали вы». Обычно, если учесть все–все получается что–то вроде этого:

[image]

Настоящие доступно лишь в единственном варианте — часть предложенных решений не получат реализацию, как минимум, пока другие, более предпочтительные в данный момент с имеющимися у компании ресурсами подходы не будут опровергнуты в ходе  эксперимента. Если вы не согласны с выбранным решением, следует опубликовать ответ в вопросе–инициативе и как можно более развернуто изложить свои мысли, пояснив, какие вы видите проблемы выбранного решения.

Что интересно, самая большая проблема социальной психологии в том, что абсолютно любой результат любого эксперимента кажется логичным и здравым после эксперимента, но не до! В случае, если вы ошиблись в вашем предположении, вы даже не вспомните о факте участия в обсуждении, но если вы о чем–то говорили и сообщество или компания взяла другой курс и он оказался ошибочным, уверяю вас, вы вспомните об этом ни раз! Это суть человеческой природы. Данный факт надо принять, понять и смириться с ним.

Если вам было что–то предельно ясно, но сообщество взяло другой крус, который оказался не верным, пожалуйста, помните про то, что ошибка часть процесса и итерационное улучшение системы небольшими шагами — единственно возможный путь к конечной цели. Ошибка — часть процесса, оскорбление — нет. Вне зависимости от того, какой следующий шаг выбрало сообщество, ваш или альтернативный, не стоит прибегать к унижением авторов принятых решений, лишь только потому, что вы с ними не согласны или они оказались не верны. Конструктивная критика — это детальный ответ с рассмотрением всех плюсов и минусов инициативы и решений. Оскорбительные высказывания о личности автора не является конструктивной критикой выбранного решения.

Можно и нужно иметь свою точку зрения по каждому вопросу, нужно о ней рассказывать остальным. Оскорблять несогласных с вами, якобы ненароком приписывая им что–то — недопустимо.

#### Возможно, сарказм — это не всегда плохо, надменность — всегда.

Stack Overflow — это база знаний и повседневный инструмент разработчика для поиска помощи в сложной ситуации. Это не сайт анекдотов и афоризмов. [На Stack Overflow мы не любим шутки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2697/6)

На Stack Overflow мы соревнуемся не в умении шутить, а в глубине знаний. Если вы хотите развлечь себя и коллег, опубликуйте самое нестандартное решение, к самой типичной задаче.

Все же, если вы решили, что без чего–то веселого по каким–то причинам ваш ответ будет не таким хорошим, помните, что сарказм и надменность это разные вещи. Если ваш «юмор» высмеивает других участников, пожалуйста, воздержитесь от публикации подобного где–либо на платформе Stack Exchange. [Правило дружелюбия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) распространяются на все сайты сети, в том числе Мету и чаты.

Быть веселым по жизни обязательно нужно, публиковать шутки на Stack Overflow не всегда можно, надменно высмеивать коллег — не следует никогда и ни при каких обстоятельствах. Мы все разные и это не делает кого–то из нас хуже. Общество начинается с единства цели и эмпатии друг к другу.

#### Модератор — гарант безопасности на сайтах, а не первый нарушитель

Модераторы выбираются сообществом, чтобы поддерживать работоспособность системы, в том числе соблюдение принятых правил. Если модератор не согласен с правилам, это не означает, что он может поступать на свое личное усмотрение, потому что его выбрали. Сообщество наделило его дополнительными возможностями для соблюдения общепринятых правил, а не реализации своей личной программы и видения мира. Ибо это уже не проявление позиции, как участника, а саботаж как модератора. В контексте выбора направлений развития сообщества модератор стоит на равных с каждым из нас: не нравятся правила, считаете, что можно улучшить систему — пожалуйста, задайте вопрос на Мете [по правилам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/6), а не единолично придумывай свои. Если модератор не может нести бремя поддержки существующих правил и следовать процессам, возможно, ему стоит отойти в сторону до тех пор, пока его не станут устраивать правила до такой степени, чтобы им следовать.

#### Модератор — это тот, кто объединяет нас

Мне лично модератор представляется неким супер–добрым и крайне человечным участником, который всегда поддержит, когда нужна поддержка, даже если ты не прав и вежливо поможет разобраться, в чем же дело. Модератор — гарант безопасности и комфорта на сайте. Он справедлив и нейтрален. Именно за это его любят и уважают.

Когда участник со статусом модератора раз за разом пытается дискредитировать кого–то на основе личной каких–то личных оценок и/или несогласия, падает уважение и доверие и к модератору, не говоря уже о негативном настрое к лицу, против которого модератор настраивает сообщество, да и к системе в целом. Не может быть процветания и блага там, где люди не могут доверять друг другу.

#### Модератор — это не только статус: с дополнительные возможностями идет дополнительная ответственность

Мы хотим сделать сайт и информацию на нем как можно более открытыми и доступными каждому. Чтобы этого достичь подобные правила введены и в рамках компании. Политика конфиденциальности для сотрудников — публично по умолчанию: все что я знаю, всем что я слышу внутри компании, я могу делиться с сообществом совершенно открыто. Все же есть часть информации, которая по идеологическим причинам скрыта от рядового участника и доступна только модераторам. Прежде чем модератор вступил в должность, он [соглашается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement), что не будет распростронять данные, доступные только модераторам.

Если модератору необходимо показать участникам какой–то тренд для принятия решения, обычно мы обезлииваем информацию, делая ее максимально абстрактной, не привязанной к конкретным участника, чтобы на них не началась «травля». Ни в коем случае, ни при каких обстоятельствах модератору недопустимо публиковать в открытый доступ конкретные имена, снимки экранов админки и т.д. Это вызвано не какой–то секретностью (за исключением адресов почты), а психологией человека.

Если модератор не может устоять перед соблазном опубликовать в открытый доступ то, что доступно только ему или он не согласен с данной политикой, опять же, возможно такому участнику не стоит выдвигать на пост модератора.

Comment: Публичные действия следует обсуждать публично. Более того это намного эффективнее многочисленных приватных обсуждений которые ни к чему не приводят.

Comment: @GreenDragon А что здесь именно надо публично обсуждать? Что не стоит нарушать [Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), особенно модераторам? Или перед каждым наказанием за нарушения надо спросить мнения каждого? Кстати, у меня вот уже скоро сотню комментариев под постом напишут и вчера было тоже "крайне эффективное" обсуждение в чате.

Comment: @GreenDragon Стоит обсуждать публичные *действия*, а не публичных *персон*. Чувствуете разницу?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, как что? Решение, почему оно было принято и как сообществу сделать так, чтобы такие ситуации минимизировать. Не надо спрашивать каждого, надо 1 раз взять и предметно объяснить.

Comment: `а не реализации своей личной программы и видения мира.` а разве модераторы, [редактирющие "хрен" и "фиг"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7140/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3) не этим занимаются?

Comment: **Вопрос**: блокировка была осуществлена за высказывание `Николасу плевать на чужие мнения` или что-то ещё? Спасибо.

Comment: @РашенБеар И да, и нет. Да — вероятно, предположение о пользе правок было ошибочно (о пользе действие написано в ответе). Нет— есть правила дружелюбия и лицензия содержимого.

Comment: @GreenDragon Чтобы не было таких ситуаций достаточно просто следовать разделу из справки [Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), то есть вести себя дружелюбно. А модератором надо быть ответственными в своих словах и действиях. Этого вполне хватит, но я не вижу для этого необходимости в постах. Но если вам нужен отдельный пост на мете, то мой пост и Николаса и они этом и говорят.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Причина блокировки — нарушения политики дружелюбия. Указанный вами комментарий в том числе.

Comment: Позиция других модераторов по данному вопросу интересна. Пока ни один из них не высказался. Спасибо.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, конечно. Только просьба, когда удаляете комментарии - сносите всю ветку, а то получается что вы мне вопрос задаете(3 комментарий ветки), а ответить не даете. Надеюсь на понимание.

Comment: _Stack Overflow — это уникальное явление_ - я вас умоляю! Сайты типа "Вопрос - Ответ" были задолго до SO. Но он действительно уникален в том, что уничтожив большинство программерских форумов, запретил живое общение. Раньше можно было на одной площадке и ответ на вопрос по программированию получить, и за жизнь перетереть. Теперь, увы...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я думаю что SO выиграл просто за счет более вменяемого интерфейса и народной модерации. Например на форумах можно опубликовать задачу и сказать "Решайте, а царь будет отдыхать")

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет и **не было** ни одного  популярного сайта/чата/списка рассылки/newsgroup/итд, открытого для всех желающих, с той же шириной охвата тем, без огромной потери в сигнал/шум соотношении (когда можно буквально сотни сотни сообщений просматривать чтобы информацию по решению нарыть, вместо всего порядка дюжины как на SO). Если, по вашему мнению, есть/были конкретные примеры обратного, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: @jfs - И тогда (до появления SO), и сейчас я использую поисковик. Зачем мне искать на одном сайте, если можно сразу на всех? И тогда, и сейчас я на первой же странице выдачи получал ответы на простые вопросы. А на сложные ответов как не было так и нет ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782709/184217), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48708150/5045688)).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: поисковик и является основным UI для большинства пользователей на Stack Overflow  (~95% траффика). Так как мне приходится искать ответы по темам, которые SE сеть не покрывает, наблюдение из моего предыдущего комментария не теоретическое, а основано на опыте множества запросов (по многим темам я полный новичок, есть темы, в которых у меня есть опыт). Впечатления могут быть разными (я видел, как некоторые люди на reddit предпочитают вопросы задавать), но SO wins, если провести эксперимент: список вопросов, офильтровать SO и клоны для одной группы, сравнить `wc -c`, `time`

Comment: @jfs - Я согласен: сейчас SO рулит. Вот только на основном en.so есть масса сайтов, где можно обсудить самые разные темы, от религии до аниме. А на ru.so ничего кроме программирования (и meta для нытья). Прихожу к выводу, что нужен дополнительный сайт(ы), что-то типа ru.live.stackoverflow или ru.flood.stackoverflow...Хотя, конечно, есть чаты, где можно потрепаться на любые темы. Но всё же, это не то.

Comment: Примерно половину ответа можно выкинуть без какого-либо ущерба для сути. А конкретно, секции от "критики" по "сарказм", включительно.

Answer (score -3):

Я не знаю, будет ли официальный ответ, но модератор довольно оскорбительно отзывался об управляющем сообществом, а до этого его поведение часто бывало на грани. Даже если он не согласен в чём-то даже с позицией управляющего сообществом недопустимо опускаться до оскорблений.

По-хорошему, модератор должен гасить конфликты и быть хладнокровным в накалённых ситуациях, но как минимум, он точно не должен создавать конфликтные ситуации. Также модераторы должны быть примеров для других участников и мне бы очень не хотелось чтобы у такого поведения появлялись подражатели. Это не я придумал, это следует из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators).

---

Я доволен, что данное поведение не осталось безнаказанным. А если поведение модератора не изменится после разблокировки, то отстранение от должности будет очень справедливым решением и, возможно, тогда потребуются новые выборы.

Comment: Вы бы не могли привести примеры его оскорблений и поведения "на грани"?

Comment: @Other Ну я точно не процитирую, но было что-то вроде "Николасу плевать на мнения других" и т.д.

Comment: А где оскорбление? Это критика.

Comment: @Other По моему мнению, это звучит оскорбительно и не является допустимой критикой. До этого такого рода "критика" лилась часто. То угрозы пойти на главную мету за то, что он закрыл вопрос "дубликатом", за якобы отличные мнения и т.д. Это вся совокупность многочисленных "критических" высказываний и подобное провокативное поведение очень даже достойно блокировки.

Comment: Разве что мнения совпали. Тогда разумнее открыть на мете вопрос, обсудить что и как стоит делать/говорить, а потом уже бан/снятие ромба. А вот так - тихо забанить модера как-то перебор. Тоже мнение.

Comment: @Other Снятия с должности пока не было. Просто пусть модератор чуток остынет. Я вот совсем не злорадствую, просто не уверен, что он бы угомонился иначе и понял бы что что-то делает не так, если честно.

Comment: Я и не сказал что было снятие. Однако это не просто участник, а модератор. Как минимум, надо было описать ситуацию, составить список требований к такому ответственному посту (типа слепой лояльности без права критики) и потом уже банить. Ведь модератором может быть почти любой участник, надо сразу дать знать что требуется.

Comment: @Other: эмоциональные выбросы не к лицу модератору. Эта роль предполагает столкновение с некрасивыми, накалёнными ситуациями -- здесь важна способность сохранять хладнокровие, рациональность¶ Практика показала, что не следует конкретные личности обсуждать, это только плодит конфликт (люди эмоционально реагируют даже, если указать на техническую ошибку в их ответе, не говоря про менее однозначные случаи). Разумно публично говорить о правилах. И необходимость "держать себя в руках" в роли модератора является самоочевидной https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: @jfs, это не отменяет необходимости поднять вопрос на мете.

Comment: @Other Наоборот к модератору предъявляются повышенные требования по сравнению с обычным участникам. А в чем должен именно быть вопрос на мете? Такое поведение должно присекаться без обсуждений, особенно в случае модераторов.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, в каком смысле? Описать ситуацию, показать как НЕ надо себя вести, предупредить будущих кандидатов что возможны такие казусы и как из них выбираться. Как раз надо освещать эти ситуации.

Comment: @andreymal, ну грубовато, конечно, грубовато.

Comment: @andreymal А вы считаете такие комментарии и переход на личности допустимыми?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вполне

Comment: @Other Про "слепую лояльность без права критики" вы сильно перегибаете, как мне кажется. Критиковать надо конкретные решения и действия, а не личности, причём без "наездов" и надуманных обвинений. Отдельный пост для данного случая вы уже создали. Для того, чтобы не было подобных ситуаций достаточно два раздела справки осилить: [Будьте дружелыбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) и [Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, а как же нет? Высказался против - получил. Хотя моё ИМХО - Николас просто обиделся за резкое замечание.

Comment: @Other Это же вообще неправда. Под разными постами Николаса бывает часто аргументированное несогласие без грубости. И что? Был хоть один подобный случай бана?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, в чате он говорит что это не первый случай, вот и это была последняя капля.

Comment: @Other Ну может когда-то и было. Но вот, допустим, за последний год. Куча комментариев оппонирующих его мнению и никого не банили (разве что этот случай, но здесь явно нельзя сказать, что это взвешенная аргументированная критика, это скорей эмоции).

Comment: Николасу не плевать на мнения других. Это точно показала история со злостным минусователем всея и всех. Изначально он серьезно был настроен провести воспитательные беседы с нарушителем и ограничиться этим, но учёл мнение части сообщества и выписал вторичный годовой бан Нарушителю.  С другой стороны мне очень понравилась работа Квертия в качестве модератора. Не раз был свидетелем, как он мягко, умело гасил конфликты между пользователями. И я считаю, что нужно поостыть всем.

Comment: Выключить компъютеры, успокоиться, отдонуть, встретить праздники и потом посмотреть на эту ситуацию другими глазами через три дня. Моё личное мнение,- это было бы большой ошибкой лишать Qwertiy модераторства.

Comment: @Other представитель власти не должен критиковать власть. Это всегда во вред обществу. Если не согласен с генеральной линией партии, обсуди это приватно. Если не удалось договориться, откажись от должности.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, он не лишён модерки. Пока, во всяком случае.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, есть такое. Но и Николас тихой сапой промолчал.

Comment: @Other я _цепной пёс кровавых режимов_ ™ и мне несколько чужды местные демократические ценности и взгляды, может быть я не прав, но я считаю, что Николас не должен отчитываться в каждом своём действии, а особенно в ситуациях способных вызвать в сообществе сомнения в устойчивости власти.

Comment: @Other Не путайте, пожалуйста, оскорбление и критику.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, видимо это сильно завязано на мнениях, но я в том сообщении больше критику увидел, нежели оскорбление.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Модераторов выбирали сообщество не для того, чтобы они во всем соглашались с линией партии, но и представлять наши интересы. Не вижу не одной причины почему здоровая, обоснованная критика могла бы навредить "власти". Слушая только одобрения далеко не уедешь. Хуже когда на не самый удачный комментарий (который, на мой взгляд, не соответствует действительности) участник получает блокировку. Более чем уверен, что будь обращение к обычному участнику, то дело ограничилось обычным удалением комментария, но никак не баном.

Comment: @FoggyFinder во-первых, представлять интересы не всегда значит потакать им. Во-вторых, администрация ресурса - это не враги пользователям, а генеральная линия партии - это не заговор против пользователей. Наконец, основа основ управления и политики - это не выяснять отношения на публике. Не стоит недооценивать коллективную бессознательную реакцию на раскол во власти. И да, модераторы должны нести большую ответственность, чем рядовые пользователи, а как следствие и большие наказания.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в моем комментарии нет того, с чем вы пытаетесь спорить (первое и второе). Блокировка учетной записи это не выяснение отношений на публике? Здесь так устроено, что многие действия в том числе и администрации логируются, скрыться от публики (мы все еще говорим о сообществе?) будет сложно.

Comment: @Suvitruf возможно беда в том, что для Николаса ruSO - это детище, за которое болит душа, а для остальных всё не так серьёзно и потому некоторые его реакции кажутся чрезмерными, а отношение к некоторым вопросам слишком серьёзным.

Comment: @FoggyFinder как я уже писал, обсудить спорные вопросы можно приватно - почта, скайп и т.п.

Comment: Кстати, свои самые первые модераторские права я потерял просто за демонстрацию власти, несмотря на то, что это никому не нанесло вреда. Фактически меня забанили навсегда за неосторожно брошенное слово. Модератор представляет закон, и закон к модератору должен быть строг, строже чем к обычным пользователям.

Comment: И наше детище тоже. Прямо говоря, в последнее время управляющий сообществом все больше принимает личных решений, с которыми много несогласных. Где обратная связь от сообщества, как нам повлиять на политику ресурса?

Comment: @AK никто не отнимает у пользователей права высказываться. Или я что-то упустил и уже были случаи удаления неудобных вопросов на Мете и бана рядовых пользователей за альтернативное мнение? Уверен, Николас принимает их в расчёт, но иногда нельзя обойтись без личных решений.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev все это было, были случаи удаления _неудобных_ вопросов с меты (после снятия овнеров), были случаи банов в чате за альтернативные мнения (тогда же)

Comment: Права высказываться действительно никто не отнимает. Только эти высказывания уже ни на что не влияют. Послушали - и сделали по-своему. Начиная с момента мета регламентов обратная связь от сообщества всё меньше и меньше принимается в расчёт. Мы высказываемся просто так, чтобы это в урну истории пошло? И меня это тревожит (feel uneasy)

Comment: @AK, какая разница кто какие решения принял? Просто всегда поступайте так, как вам кажется правильно в данной ситуации.

Comment: @AK я не понимаю как можно дискуссию вести, когда вы (не только вы естественно) сами себе противоречите. К примеру, с одной стороны вы говорите, что "высказывания ни на что не влияют", а с другой "обратная связь от сообщества всё меньше и меньше принимается в расчёт" -- одновременно оба не могут быть правдивыми. Не ведитесь на поводу у троллей и популистов. Будем считать, что первое высказывание только эмоциональный смысл передаёт и не имеет смысла буквально. Про второе: можете хотя бы самую слабую версию вашего утверждения защитить: "есть пример, когда  мнение сообщества проигнорировано"?

Comment: @jfs , пример, когда мнение сообщества проигнорировано - [Отмена результатов выборов владельцев чата](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6713/Отмена-результатов-выборов-владельцев-чата)

Comment: @jfs 1) Как вести дискуссию, когда вам кажется, что ваш оппонент противоречит сам себе: спросите его о этом противоречии. 2) О примере такого игнорирования я [сегодня говорил в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44288528#44288528).

Comment: @GreenDragon: я не вижу, где "мнение сообщества проигнорировано". Я чат редко посещаю, но результатом не удивлён. Как валидность самих выборов под вопросом, так и поведение модераторов чата под сомнением. То что конкретное модераторское решение публично обсуждается это плохо. Публично следует только правила и ценности обсуждать. На личности не следует переходить.

Comment: @AK: я привёл вам конкретный пример где вы себе явно противоречите. Вы это отрицаете?¶ Я не вижу по вашей ссылке конкретного примера. Есть какие-то общие слова. Если у вас позиция: "высказывания ни на что не влияют" -- вам должно быть очень легко привести многочисленные примеры. Я прошу хотя бы один.

Comment: @jfs , вы (не только вы естественно) - не видите, а я - вижу. Это нормально. Посмотрите на причину, по которой были сняты овнеры, посмотрите на реакцию комьюните-менеджера на справедливые вопросы. Валидность тех выборов признана самим Николасом, куда уж валиднее.

Comment: @jfs Я [приводил](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44288812#44288812) пример -  историю с автоудалением комментариев.

Comment: @GreenDragon: вы имеете право на своё мнения, я на своё. Вы не имеете право своё мнение за мнение сообщества выдавать

Comment: @AK: это ссылка на другое сообщение. Уже лучше, но опять таки расплывчатые обвинения: там несколько обсуждений, несколько разных позиций и ситуация ещё не разрешена. Если как есть [чересчур обширные] regex останутся, тогда можно говорить,  но пока рано. Сложно непротиворечивый завершённый пример найти?

Comment: @jsf другой пример, который я [приводил](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44288739#44288739) сегодня: раньше мнение сообщества учитывалось больше (разного рода голосования и обсуждения на мете), [недавно пришло разъяснение, что голосования не принимаются в расчёт, мнения не принимаются в расчёт и вообще есть ряд вопросов, по которым компания не принимает в расчёт мнение коммьюнити](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/213987).

Comment: @jsf Также видите ли какая штука... у меня по этим вопросам [особое мнение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), но я пока не успеваю его оформить целостным постом на мете, а пока отдельные фрагменты выхватываю, плюс я по факту просто пересказываю не своё мнение - а перевожу в конструктивное поле негатив бунтующих, так-то у меня более консервативные позиции.

Comment: @AK: случайно, я [именно эту ссылку о голосованиях и читал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899): согласно ей все окончательные решения принимаются компанией. Вопросы на Мете могут быть прочитаны, могут быть не прочитаны. Голоса, консенсус не являются решающими. "Убедительность и основательность" могут приниматься во внимание, но решение всегда за компанией¶ Это интересно. То есть официальная позиция, что компания может игнорировать консенсус на Мете, а есть явные примеры: есть консенсус, а компания по другому поступила?

Comment: @jfs А, вижу. Извините это непреднамеренно.

Comment: @jfs Мне кажется, что эту ветку пора отдельно оформлять, тут другая тема была - про модератора и комменеджера, ответ есть, плюс в чате есть [подробности](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44289115#44289115). Меня уже само это объявление тревожит (feel uneasy), плюс глядя на уже произошедшее с тех пор я вижу негативные последствия.

Comment: @AK: я просто вижу необоснованные заявления от людей, которые по моему мнению способны к более конструктивному диалогу. Факты таковы: [статус-завершено]—593 [статус-отклонено]—24.

Comment: @GreenDragon: [статус-отклонено](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5496/23044) говорит, что *есть* некоторые сомнения в валидности выборов.

Comment: @jfs А я вижу, что данный разворот курса ошарашил не только меня, но и других людей. Видели в чате вопросы ([раз](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44280275#44280275), [два](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=44279180#44279180)) VladD? [Комментарий Suvitruf](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44290716#44290716) - это участники консервативные во взглядах, вполне лояльные, много лет на сайте, активны на мете и всё равно есть вопросы. И если даже такие консервативные люди как мы обеспокоены (feel uneasy)  - то наверное не всё ладно в королевстве?

Comment: @AK: лично я всегда придерживался позиции, что миссию сайта следует защищать вне зависимости от популярного на данный момент мнения. Поэтому меня интересуют *конкретные* примеры, когда компания вопреки мнению сообщества поступала бы (конкретный вред). Я знаю один пример обратного, когда на поводу популярного мнения пострадала на мой взгляд миссия сайта (введение "учебное задание" причины закрытия -- популярно, но отношение к задающим вопрос неправильное задаёт и не на те вещи акцент: полезность вопроса/ответов для будущих читателей является приоритетной, а не то кто/почему его задал).

Comment: @FoggyFinder Там не один комментарий, а наблюдающееся систематично деструктивное поведение, создающее много шума.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я не думаю, что смогу вас переубедить, поэтому даже не буду пытаться.В ответе четко сказано что блокировка из-за нарушение `be-nice`. Блокировка была сделано в скором времени после "спорного" комментария. Думаю, вывод о поводе достаточно очевиден. Что касается причины, то она, конечно, в другом.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Так нет никакого противоречия в том, что до этого "спорного" комментария была предыстория нехороший казусов. Поэтому я считаю что без блокировки здесь никак, так как модератор вряд ли бы понял, что делает что-то не так. И даже после разблокировки не факт, что что-то поймёт.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov давайте обойдемся без домысливаний ("вряд-ли понял", "делает что-то не так")? По факту есть только "спорный" комментарий. Какие конкретно "нехорошие казусы" вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Ну вот к примеру война открытий-закрытий https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6896/revisions и переход на личности с домысливаниями в правках 4 и 8.

Comment: @jfs, обратите внимание на историю правок и поймете что статус отклонено предложение приобрело после инцидента. А за сообщество здесь никто не может говорить, самые объективные критерии - число поддержки на вопросе/ответе/комментарии.