# Удаление части комментария с изменением смысла

Tags: поддержка, комментарии

Недавно я написал [комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7515/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5#comment30812_7515):

> Отлично ты даты подобрал. [Этот вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7200/178988) был задан 28 апреля, а твоя статистика заканчивается на 27м.

но он практически сразу оказался отредактирован (не мной) до:

> [Этот вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7200/178988) был задан 28 апреля, а твоя статистика заканчивается на 27м.

После чего последовал нерелевантный исходному смыслу ответ:

> Указанный вами вопрос не удален, в нем нет удаленных ответов (один ответ преобразован в комментарий).

---

На мой взгляд, внесённая правка изменяет оригинальный смысл комментария (указать на несоответствие описанных временных рамок некоторым событиям) на совершенно непонятный (просто ссылка на вопрос, не связанный с приведённой статистикой).

**Итак, что было не так с этим комментарием и допустимо ли подобное редактирование вообще?**

Comment: Три вопроса - три ответа:

1. Комментарий ничуть не пострадал от того что из него эту едкость убрали.

2. Чтобы не было нерелевантных исходному смыслу ответов, постарайтесь пожалуйста писать более содержательные комментарии/вопросы. Выражайте свои вопросы яснее.

3. Подобное редактирование допустимо, хотя и нежелательно, а в данном конкретном случае - весьма спорно.

Comment: Комментарии править — плохо. Их надо удалять сразу, либо оставлять. Мы это уже выяснили. По комментарию вам отдельно отписались в чате, а после вовсе восстановили комментарий (без относительно заданного вами вопроса).