# Настоящие? модераторы сообщества

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На [странице участников](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) всплывающая подсказка для вкладки "модераторы" выглядит странно. На enSO она выглядит как "Наши текущие модераторы сообщества"

> [image: всплывающие модераторы]

Comment: На enSO она всё же должна быть на английском :)

Comment: *выглядит **как** ...*

Answer (score 3):

Это игра слов из серии «иностранный агент». Мне тоже такой перевод не нравится. Попахивает каким-то выпендрёжом, типа другие ромбы не из списка не являются настоящими, а какие-то кукольные (сразу вспоминаются марионетки и прочие sock puppet) что ли.

Я бы предложил вариант «действующие». Хотя это тоже может быть не совсем корректным утверждением в случае нахождения [модератора в бане](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7200/176217) или обычного лентяйства. Но такие ситуации всё же из ряда вон выходящие.

---

Утвердил вариант ["Текущие модераторы сообщества"](https://ru.traducir.win/string/8029)

Comment: Может как-то вроде "избранные модераторы"?

Comment: @АндрейNOP вообще «избранные» некорректно использовать, так как в списке могут присутствовать и назначенные (без демократических выборов).

Comment: Ну тогда остаётся дословный перевод

Comment: @АндрейNOP [текущие?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE7X8.png)