# Что происходит с нашим новым модератором и подписанием модераторского соглашения?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Заметил на английской мета-мете непонятные посты от нового модератора @αλεχολυτ (в хронологическом порядке):

- [Settings tab (with only Preferences subtab) on every user profile is visible by moderator prior signing the Mod Agreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388580)
- [Moderator Agreement signing deadline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388620/353058)
- [How can I ask a question regarding moderator related issues if I don't have access to the Teachers' Lounge or the Stack Moderators team?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388702/353058)

Вроде как человек специально промедлил с подписанием [модераторского соглашения](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) (зачем?), у него временно отобрали часть прав, а дальше началась какая-то непонятная драма.

Было бы интересно услышать от @αλεχολυτ, что там происходит, из первых уст.

Comment: События были объяснены [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388708/203057). Модератор, о котором идет речь, еще не подписал модераторское соглашение, и теперь ему запрещен доступ к инструментам, требующим подписания этого соглашения.

Comment: Не переживайте, всё уже давно подписано, всё разрулим.

Comment: @aepot А из-за чего весь сыр-бор тогда? Официальное объяснение бы не помешало.

Comment: Да, я не понимаю, почему вы так спорите о Мета Stack Exchange...

Comment: @Cerbrus события были объяснены так, как это увидел автор ответа, но они не могли и не могут быть подкреплены фактами. А факты, я надеюсь, мы скоро (6-8 недель) узнаем от персонала.

Comment: Простое тестирование системы. Сыр-бор если и есть, то только в текущих устоях SE

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Может свое объяснение напишете? Пока без пруфов, если их нет.

Comment: *"Простое тестирование системы"* - полистал MSE по-диагонали, скорее похоже на "бесцельное раздражение системы", причем с наездом в тоне, типа "ачотак?".

Comment: Пока писать что-то достойное ответа я не готов, хочу как минимум дождаться реакции сотрудников.

Comment: *"А факты, я надеюсь, мы скоро (6-8 недель) узнаем от персонала"* - вы явно занимаетесь чем-то не тем ..

Comment: @Kromster ну как бесцельное. Может хоть дыру в процессе назначения модераторов ликвидируют. Когда техническая система основана на доверии, а не на причинно-следственных связях и корректно запрограммированной логике - это очень удручающая ситуация.

Comment: Модератор забанен в чате всего через неделю после избрания, это похоже рекорд? αλεχολυτ жжот...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight но всё-таки не на сайте! [А бывало ведь и такое](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7200/176217)!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Вы не подписали модераторское соглашение, а затем довольно агрессивно пожаловались на то, что вас удалили из чата, который требует от вас подписания этого соглашения. Вы утверждаете, что «нет фактов», но это очень просто: подписываете соглашение, и вы возвращаетесь в модераторский чат. Вы пытаетесь внести в правила подписание модераторского соглашения, но то, как вы это делаете, просто непродуктивно.

Comment: @Kromster Не согласен с вами. Во первых это всё интересно. То что большинство (а возможно все кроме αλεχολυτ) сразу или почти сразу подписывали договор, не значит что все так будут делать. Зачем давать период в 30 (или 60 я уже запутался) дней для подписания договора, а потом блокировать через неделю, мол а почему не подпсиано? Пусть тогда обновят справку и правила. К чему дан этот перод, когда можно не подписывать не очень понимаю. Возможно они считают, что чтобы всё прочитать не достаточно пару дней

Comment: @αλεχολυτ читаю ваши комментарии на MSE и по ним видно, что вы с гонором наезжаете на тех кто вам отвечает или комментирует и уходите от ответов. С простым тестированием системы на нестыковки это соотносится достаточно слабо. Вы зачем-то практически хамите. Пока не понимаю, это ваша позиция или слабое владение английским.

Comment: @Kromster Скорее «система раздражена тем, что люди не хотят слепо делать, что говорят»

Comment: @EzioMercer все то же самое можно было бы делать без такого гонора и сокрытия целей )

Comment: @Cerbrus Зачем дают период для подписания договора? Зачем тогда вприницпе дают ромб до подписания? Зачем сразу дают ромб, а потом ждут пока подпишут, а потом ещё они раньше указанного времени бесятся?

Comment: @nomnoms12 дело не столько в том *что*, сколько в том *как* )

Comment: @nomnoms12 но это не абстрактная "система", а такие же, как мы с вами, живые люди, которые из Х минут своего волонтерского времени и внимания должны тратить Y минут на то, чего можно было бы избежать.

Comment: @Nofate все же не все из них волонтеры. В остальном согласен

Comment: @Kromster Это безусловно, но когда пишешь одно и то же по 100 раз уже хочешь не хочешь нервы сдают (по крайней мере мне так же кажется как и вам) :)

Comment: @Nofate Не согласен. Есть сотрудники, которых наняли специально для поддержания платформы. И эти сотрудники не стесняются навязывать нам правила, когда им это нужно. Вопросы на мете адресованы как раз им, как я понял

Comment: @nomnoms12 пока там участвовали в основном модераторы. Да, проблему получения прав до подписания соглашения подсветили, на том можно было и остановиться.

Comment: @EzioMercer, почему указан этот период, не очень важно ... Пользователь мог просто спросить о периоде и предложить его изменить. Вместо этого он жаловался на то, что его удалили, выдвигал безосновательные обвинения в злоупотреблении властью и спорил с людьми, которые пытались объяснить...

Comment: @Cerbrus Это очень даже важно. Жалоба вполне обоснована, потому что как раз он был удалён из чатов, до истечения указанного срока

Comment: @EzioMercer одна из бед ruSO как раз в том, что тут не все умеют формулировать мысли и вопросы по теме. Некоторые (не буду пока показывать пальцем) спрашивая А, называют вопрос Б, а имеют в виду получение ответа на С. В любом случае, виновник торжества точно не по 100 раз отвечал, и уж должен был догадаться, добавить уточнение в свой вопрос на MSE, а не припираться в коментах ссылаясь на свои другие комменты. **MSE это тоже База Знаний**, а не справочная или жалобная книга )

Comment: @EzioMercer его жалоба должна была быть вопросом и предложением. Но нет, он выбрал агрессивный подход. Это контрпродуктивно.

Comment: @Cerbrus А насколько продуктивно удалять модератора из чата? Вместо того, чтобы сделать свою работу и обновить справку, сотрудникам оказалось легче «забанить» модератора. Нет модератора — нет проблем

Comment: @Kromster Да, тут вы правы, безусловно. Но просто под каждым таким вопросом ему пишут "просто подпиши договор", я потому сказал, что уже 100 раз отвечал на такие вопросы, а не именно то что в последнем вопросе. А так ваша правда :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Поиск дыр в системе - это благородное занятие, никто не спорит. Но отдельный вопрос - как сообщать о них. Обычно все-таки пишут пост на мету с тегом "баг", а тут какие-то окольные пути, вызывающие раздражение у обитателей английской меты. Вы, как модератор, по идее должны помогать решать конфликты, а не создавать новые.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Тык а что, все правильно. Его туда не должны были вообще добавлять до подписания. Так что нужно и удалить, и пофиксить систему.

Comment: @nomnoms12 у него вообще не должно было быть доступа к этому чату, поэтому я бы сказал, что это было очень продуктивно.

Comment: @nomnoms12 забанил такой же модератор. Не сотрудник.

Comment: @EzioMercer вот после первого же вопроса или непонимания в каментах, надо было поправить вопрос и уточнить в нем этот момент, а не нетактично уходить от ответа и разыгрывать драму вида *"I'm really really curios and discouraged **HOW without any proof** of information about did someone signed the Agreement or doesn't signed the people can make decisions"* и *"@ColleenV "You should not have access to those spaces unless you have signed the agreement." Why do you think so? Where it's stated officially (by staff)?"*

Comment: @Cerbrus И если это было бы самого начала, то у нашего "тестировщика" не было бы никаких вопросов, но тут ему сказали одно, а не деле наказали раньше времени. С агрессивной интонацией согласен - это не уместно, но всё же суть была не том, но тут уже не избежать человеческого фактора :)

Comment: @EzioMercer опять неправильно рассматриваете. Не наказали, а убрали данную авансом возможность (доступ к модераторским чатам)

Comment: @Kromster Это (насколько я понял) было сказано из-за того что его забанили не проверив реально он подписал или нет, а лишь основываясь на разговорах между собой

Comment: @EzioMercer, он продолжал спорить, когда ситуация была объяснена. Он продолжал заявлять о "злоупотреблении властью"... Это было очень непрофессионально и непродуктивно. Все модераторы могут видеть, подписал ли модератор соглашение. Он еще не сделал.

Comment: @EzioMercer судя по тону комментаторов, он и в чате себя аналогично вызывающе вел ..

Comment: @Kromster Да, но одно дело у тебя изначально чего-то нет, а другое дело дали на обещанное время, а потом отобрали раньше времени. Представьте что вам дали разрешение, на тест драйв машины, а потом вам говорят выходить, как только вы сели в него. Вам же будет обидно? Мне бы лично было бы обидно :)

Comment: @EzioMercer сравнение с тест-драйвом неуместное. Тут речь не о приятном досуге, а об инструментах, доступ к которым несет юридические последствия.

Comment: @Kromster Ну там уже я не могу ничего сказать, что было в модераторском чате, возможно будет ясно, когда αλεχολυτ даст официальный ответ. Но я так понял, что мы дождёмся его в лучшем случае через полтора месяца...

Comment: @EzioMercer пример некорректный. Более правильная аналогия бы была - "вам выдали корпоративный ноутбук с потенциальным доступом к перс.данным некоторых клиентов, до подписания контракта и NDA. Как только выяснили, что вы не спешите подписывать и вообще как-то неконструктивно настроены - забрали, от греха подальше."

Comment: @Kromster Чёрт, только писал, про почти тоже самое, но с банковскими данными :) Я это сказал в пример того, что дали, а потом отобрали. Понятно что ситуация далеко не одинковая, но суть была именно в чувствах. Ну т.е. это некорректное поведение со стороны тех, кто дал этот ноут, а не того кому дали ноут

Comment: @EzioMercer, тот, кому дали ноутбук, затем пожаловался на публичной платформе, что они хотят вернуть ноутбук, и когда общественность сказала им, что им нужно сначала подписать соглашение, этот человек стал агрессивным и спорным ... Он такой же сильно виноват.

Comment: @Cerbrus я бы убрал слово "такой же" из конца комментария. Иначе непонятно в чем другие участники MSE виноваты )

Comment: @Kromster Я согласен, но я подозреваю, что в переводе могут отсутствовать некоторые вещи, так как я использую переводчик для общения здесь :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus Зависит от того в дальнейшем такое отношение будет ко всем новым модераторам или это было только в отношенни к тому кто нажаловался. Если этого теперь будут требовать у всех, то вопрос значит решён, нет если это было в частном порядке, то вопрос всё ещё остаётся открытым и ничто не будет мешать следующему модератору-тестировщику сделать всё ровно тоже самое

Comment: @Kromster "Такой же" был не к участниками MSE, а к тем кто дал ноут - т.е. сотрудникам, которые так организовали свою работу :)

Comment: @EzioMercer Извините, но ничто не оправдывает его жалобы, его споры и его права. Он должен был сделать простой отчет об ошибке, вместо этого беспорядка.

Comment: @Cerbrus С этим я уже давно согласился :) Агрессия была лишней

Comment: Мне очень интересно, будут ли как-то в последствии извиняться люди, которые публикуют свои догадки как факты, реально таковых не имея, или просто потрут свои комментарии/сообщения? Так же мне интересно, почему те, у кого есть информация (реальные факты) не пытаются апеллировать тем, кто фактов не имеет.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Если мои догадки как-то вас зацепят/обидят/вызовут неприязнь, то я, коненчно, извинюсь, но для сохранения истории, не буду удалять свои комментарии

Comment: @αλεχολυτ если мои догадки неверны и как-то вас задевают, то я, конечно, тоже извиняюсь (простите), но пока что ваше поведение действительно выглядит контрпродуктивным. И даже этот ваш комментарий - сеете больше тени, чем проясняете. Ждем вашей версии событий )

Comment: Смотрю его другие посты на MSE - начиналось все хорошо - пачка багрепортов, все вежливо и конструктивно .. где-то поезд свернул не туда ..

Comment: @Kromster Щас пойдут ещё догадки Но всё же предположу, что из чата его удалили во время оживлённого спора/разговора вот и пошло поехало :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ты должен был бороться со злом, а не примкнуть к нему...))

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Возможно, я неправильно понял ситуацию, и пока происходит что-то странное: вы сначала избираетесь в модераторы, на стадии предварительного голосования вы видите, что вас точно изберут; вас избирают; и вы почему-то не хотите подписывать мод.соглашение.....  Возможно, такого вихря событий допускать не стоило ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Зонтик смотрите шире, он завел кучу багов за этот период на MSE

Comment: @Зонтик Такое ощущение, что вы написали этот комментарий пропустив абсолютно все разговоры на эту тему...

Comment: @EzioMercer нет, я понимаю, что αλεχολυτ заметил нестыковк(у/и), и пытается об этом сообщить, но проходит это как-то странно.  [Этот](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388702/) пост  похож на претензию (цитата: *And I don't have access to chat at all?*); ну и меня удивил этот комментарий: *"SE staff then followed up by further restricting αλεχολυτ's access to these tools and spaces." Are you sure? Do you know it reliable? Who did it and why they did it before checking is there Agreement signed by me or not signed? Just based on the lack of my answer about that in chat? Nonsense!*

Comment: @Зонтик Вот теперь видно, что вы прочитали обсуждения тут и там, молодцы! Но предыдущий комментарий это никак не объясняет, если вы из-за этого отписались :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я правильно понял, что всё уже решилось? (Просмотрел свёрнутые комментарии на посте с MSE, но возникло сомнение).

Comment: всё правильно, долой диктатуру демократии

Answer (score 8):

Прошёл уже месяц с момента появления вопроса. Я бы опубликовал ответ и раньше, но даже хорошо, что произошли некоторые другие события, которые отвлекли внимание общественности от этого случая. Тем не менее, я обещал ответить, как буду готов, и вот мой ответ с разъяснением ситуации. Надеюсь, что многое (если не всё) вам станет понятнее.

На текущий момент вступление модератора в должность после победы на выборах происходит в несколько этапов:

- Автоматический подсчёт голосов приводит к тому, что победитель (победители) автоматически же получает "ромб" на сайте (раньше это делалось вручную сотрудниками компании).
- Имея ромб на сайте можно совершать некоторые действия, недоступные обычным участникам, а также иметь доступ к некоторым страницам, используемым модераторами в своей повседневной модераторской деятельности. В частности, доступ к закрытым модераторским чатам. Персональные данные пользователей модератору в таком переходном периоде (можно сказать, полумодератору) недоступны.
- В ручном режиме менеджер сообщества выдаёт доступ в приватное модераторское сообщество Stack Moderators Team (на базе SO for Teams).
- Далее требуется в определённые сроки подписать модераторское соглашение, чтобы получить полный набор инструментов модератора.

С подписанием соглашения я решил не торопиться. Подписывать, не вникая в детали, и сразу бросаться обрабатывать тревоги и банить неугодных пользователей я не хотел. А раз уж есть официально разрешённый период осмыслить происходящее, то почему бы этим не воспользоваться? Заодно решил чуть поглубже потестить (вы знаете, я люблю это дело), а что же такого можно сделать, надев ромб, но пока ещё не подписав соглашение. В частности в этот период и появились некоторые посты на MSE.

Наличие подобных постов, судя по всему, очень странно повлияло на некоторых модераторов (имеется в виду модераторов с других сайтов SE, а не с ruSO). Почему-то возникло подозрение, что я могу (политика "предполагай хорошие намерения" почему-то не сработала) в таком промежуточном состоянии иметь доступ к персональным данным пользователей (или даже самих коллег-модераторов), а так как я никакого соглашения ещё не подписал, то и наказать меня за потенциальное разглашение чего-либо нельзя. Шок! И шок этот был настолько сильным, что меня забанили в чате модераторов. Способ бана в чате довольно извращённый, потому что никто не был готов к тому, что придётся вообще банить участника с модераторскими привилегиями, не лишая при этом его ромба. Здесь стоит заметить, что блокировать в одной конкретной комнате нельзя и поэтому меня лишили доступа КО ВСЕМ чатам SE. Чуть позже, меня лишили и доступа к Stack Moderators Team. После этого пришлось задать упомянутый ранее вопрос на MSE: [How can I ask a question regarding moderator related issues if I don't have access to the Teachers' Lounge or the Stack Moderators team?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388702/339911) С вопросом этим отдельная история, потому как от уважаемых коллег модераторов начали появляться ответы с переходами на личность вопрошающего. А мы все тут хорошо знаем, что на SO ответ надо давать по сути вопроса, без акцента на том, кто его задаёт. На моё удивление такой ответ оказался сильно заплюсованным, а мою тревогу на нём о том, что из ответа надо бы убрать всю нерелевантную информацию с описанием того, какой плохой этот участник, задающий такие вопросы, и как сильно отвечающий в нём разочарован, отклонили. В общем, удивлению моему не было предела. Все те ценности, которые пропагандирует SO на своей платформе, оказались пшиком. Можно давать ответы с переходом на личности, можно отклонять тревоги об этом и т.д.

Стоит заметить, что ромб на сайте у меня при этом не снимали. Т.е. все те "бонусы", которые можно делать на сайте без подписания соглашения (кроме доступа к чатам в режиме записи и ModTeams) у меня остались. Получается очень странная ситуация - боялись, что я что-то натворю, имея инструменты модератора, но на удивление, доступа к ним не лишили. Но лишили возможности задавать вопросы приватно другим модераторам и сотрудникам. Пришлось писать через форму обратной связи.

Но самое замечательное во всём этом, что на момент, когда меня лишили доступа к Teachers' Lounge (TL) чату, и тем более, когда позднее меня лишили доступа к ModTeams, соглашение было мной подписано уже как ДВОЕ СУТОК НАЗАД! Т.е. модераторы чата лишили меня доступа просто по причине отсутствия моего ответа. Ладно, с ними понятно, испугались, а проверить статус подписания соглашения не могли. Но вот доступ к ModTeams предоставляется или закрывается ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО сотрудниками компании. Как и почему так произошло, что сотрудник компании не смог проверить факт подписания мною соглашения (даже модераторы сайта имеют такую возможность), для меня остаётся загадкой. Я пока не могу придумать ничего более вразумительного как то, что меня просто решили так своеобразно наказать за то, что вскрылась "дыра в системе", когда избранный модератор, ещё не подписал соглашение, но уже что-то может. Система (да и люди в этой системе) оказалась к этому не готова.

Вместо благодарности за нахождение такой проблемы в системе, меня неправомерно забанили, оплевали в постах и комментах. А после возвращения всех регалий не извинились. Хочется верить, что ситуация когда-нибудь изменится.

При этом многие пользователи (даже модераторы с других сайтов) совершенно не имея информации о статусе подписания мной соглашения, начинали меня порицать в том, что надо было сразу подписать, нельзя таким давать доступ, надо было просто зарепортить баг-репорт и т.д. и т.п. Кое-кто даже пришёл на нашу Мету с MSE подливать масла в комменты, не имея ровным счётом ВООБЩЕ НИКАКИХ ФАКТОВ о том, когда я подписал соглашение и что происходит. Видимо, просто кому-то хотелось поболтать и хайпануть.

Если остались вопросы - задавайте. Буду рад ответить. За поболтать - заходите в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Comment: О дырах в безопасности не принято сообщать через открытый багтрекер, так что "оплевали" вас не без оснований...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight безопасности? у меня написано "дыра в системе", а не в безопасности. Кажется, что опять продолжается додумывание того, чего нет.

Comment: Спасибо что рассказали! +1. По самой ситуации - вы повели себя неконструктивно и у вас забрали выданное авансом ("лучше перебдеть, чем недобдеть"). Вместо конструктивного разбора - вы стали нарываться. Плюс позиция, что вам все "должны". -1. Так что извиняться перед коллегами по цеху стоило бы вам. Надеюсь сейчас конфликт исчерпан.

Comment: @Kromster ну то есть вы считаете, что "коллеги по цеху" с переходом на личности ведут себя конструктивно? Это не имеет никакого отношения к "лучше перебдеть, чем недобдеть". И наоборот, я не вижу ничего неконструктивного в поведении αλεχολυτ.

Comment: @Kromster "Вместо конструктивного разбора" - вопрос на метамете - это и есть попытка конструктивного разбора. "Так что извиняться перед коллегами по цеху стоило бы вам" - ну такое, я не вижу за что тут надо извиняться.

Comment: @insolor давайте посмотрим, какие примеры "перехода на личности" вы можете привести? Основной неконструктив, как мне видится, был в том, что он не объяснял целей своего поведения и в то же время агрессивно вопрошал ко всем "а вы ТОЧНО УВЕРЕНЫ что я не подписывал???!!1". Вопрос на MSE (оба, и особенно комментарии) были в ключе "я вам не скажу что я и зачем я делаю, а вы докажите!" Так что извиниться стоило бы, но судя по заявлениям типа *"Все те ценности, которые пропагандирует SO на своей платформе, оказались пшиком"*, ТС все еще в обиде. Если хотите - продолжим в чате.

Comment: @Kromster, я обычный мимокрокодил, не вникал глубоко в тему, полагаясь то что написал αλεχολυτ (да, это не совсем добросовестно, признаю). В идеале, неплохо было бы, если бы αλεχολυτ сам привел примеры перехода на личности и подтверждения других фактов, описанных в ответе - в самом ответе. Возможно почитаю подробнее вопросы и ответы на метамете (но, если честно - лень).

Comment: О том, что пропагандируемые ценности здесь только для «простых смертных», а сама «элита» видит себя выше этого, было, кажется, понятно ещё со времён первого закручивания гаек и исхода активных участников, когда Николас провёл офигенную логическую цепочку «оспариваешь решение Николаса => не согласен (но не ругаешься) => пассивная агрессия => агрессия => бан». Ничего нового (к сожалению).

Comment: @Kromster А почему нужно объяснять цели своего поведения? Каким-то Оруэллом запахло.

Comment: @Kromster А что вы имеете в виду под конструктивным поведением? Тупо не вникая согласиться на всё, или молча отказаться от ромба?

Comment: Очевидный пример перехода на личности — https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388708/154101. Вместо ответа на поставленный вопрос — «я недоволен поведением ТС». Кто он вообще такой, чтобы давать оценки? Его мнение не спрашивали и он может держать своё мнение при себе.

Comment: @VladD в данном контексте, конструктивное поведение предполагает развернутые ответы на вопросы и декларирование целей. Таким образом, чтобы других участников присоединять к достижению поставленных целей, а не антагонизировать. Полагаю, что цель была иная, чем предложенные вами 2 варианта ;-) Переход на личности, это скорее все же когда аргументы строятся на том, что "я не доволен А, потому что А *такой-сякой-нехороший*". Когда же аргументы строятся на "я недоволен *поведением* А", это скорее обсуждение поведения, а не личности А.

Comment: @VladD *"А почему нужно объяснять цели своего поведения?"* - совместная деятельность предполагает следование выработанным правилам, коммуникацию для определения и достижения общих целей. Представьте себе постройку дома, на которой никто правилам не следует и никому ничего не объясняет )

Comment: @Kromster Я не совсем понимаю, почему конструктивное поведение заключается в объяснении своих внутренних мотивов. Никто не должен «демонстрировать верность идеалам», это не комсомольское собрание. То, что вы называете «конструктивным поведением», предполагает наличие какого-либо права у всей этой клики судить мои или чьи-то ещё мотивы. Никто такого права им не давал, и частью модераторского соглашения это (надеюсь) не является.

Comment: @Kromster: Плохая аналогия, как известно, подобна котёнку с дверцей. Нет, совместная деятельность ничего такого не предполагает. А вот правилам ТС как раз следовал, вы здесь выдаёте желаемое за действительное.

Comment: Много раз было, когда я выражал недовольство модерацией с указанием конкретных имён и конкретных поступков, и это всё удалялось Николасом как раз под соусом «нельзя переходить на личности». А когда то же самое против ТС, то можно, да?

Comment: @VladD не стоит передергивать, конструктивное поведение не *"заключается в объяснении"*. Однако "объяснением" можно добиться существенно большего, чем "авыдокажите!". Не хотите - не объясняйте, и тогда не удивляйтесь, что вам не помогают )

Comment: [Ссылка на мое мнение в чате (исходя из положения дел на конец апреля)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63428507#63428507)

Comment: @VladD совместная деятельность очень даже это всё предполагает. Попробуйте совместно поднять десяток 3м труб на 3й этаж, не следуя заведенным правилам подъема и не общаясь с напарником )))

Comment: @Kromster Ваши слова: «в данном контексте, конструктивное поведение предполагает развернутые ответы на вопросы и декларирование целей». Так что по вашим словам, да, заключается в объяснении (и возможно ещё чём-то). Дискасс.

Comment: @Kromster Снова аналогия, которая ничего не доказывает. Сама аналогия, кстати, тоже хромает: при заносе труб я не должен никому рассказывать о своих мотивах, если моя бесплатная помощь не устраивает кого-то, то auf Wiedersehen.

Comment: @Kromster Вопрос не в том, помогают или нет, тут всё понятно, помогать не будут. Вопрос в том, что собственные правила площадки нарушают те, кто должен по идее следить за правилами. Элиты, да, всегда считают, что правила не для них, и даже не замечают свои нарушения.

Comment: @VladD фраза *«**в данном контексте**, конструктивное поведение **предполагает** развернутые ответы на вопросы и декларирование целей»* описывает некоторую часть конструктивного поведения. Не понимаю как вы это сводите к *"конструктивное поведение заключается в"*. Частное не есть общее. "В данном контексте, соблюдение ПДД предполагает переход на зеленый" у вас превращается в "не совсем понимаю, почему **соблюдение ПДД заключается в** переходе на зеленый". Надеюсь я вас неправильно понял, и мы говорим все же об одном и том же.

Comment: @VladD выше вы утверждали *"Нет, совместная деятельность ничего такого [следование выработанным правилам, коммуникацию] не предполагает"*. Окей, привел вам аналогию, как вам вдвоем с напарником выполнить работу не следуя правилам и не коммуницируя. Вы пишете - *"при заносе труб я не должен никому рассказывать о своих мотивах"* - мотивы тут почти не при чем. Без банального "ты бери снизу и подавай, я буду принимать, только не все сразу, а по две давай" - это и есть коммуникация.

Comment: @VladD *"тут всё понятно, помогать не будут"* - это печально, если заранее ставят себя в рамки "одиночки", который никому ничего не должен объяснять, и чуть что не так *"auf Wiedersehen"*.  *"Элиты, да, всегда считают, что правила не для них, и даже не замечают свои нарушения"* - тут есть над чем подумать .. вы как раз выше приводили примеры своих нарушений которые не считали нарушениями ..

Comment: @Kromster: По поводу общего и частного, я специально для вас дописал «(и возможно ещё чём-то)», чтобы вы не придирались к этим мышам. По поводу аналогии, давайте я ещё раз повторю, что аналогии доказательством не являются и никогда не являлись, так что эта ветка дискуссии не имеет смысла.

Comment: По поводу auf Wiedersehen, да, к людям, которые бесплатно работают на коммерческую организацию надо бы относиться уважительно. Бесплатная работа в отсутствие уважения — это какой-то мазохизм как на мой вкус. Если A пришёл к N бесплатно помогать нести трубу, а N _требует_ у A срочно, «как можно скорее» подписать какие-то обязывающие A бумаги, и запрещает пока бумаги не подписаны даже ходить по помещению, то N должен бы по уму рассчитывать на скорый auf Wiedersehen, а всё остальное есть хуцпа.

Comment: @Kromster Единственное моё действие, которое я упоминал — несогласие с Николасом. Я согласен на то. что нельзя упоминать конкретные имена только если автора [вот этого ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388708/154101) забанят. Правила либо одинаковые для всех, включаю элиту, либо auf Wiedersehen. Впрочем, Николас изобрёл прекрасное: несогласие с ним — это нарушение правил, а вот его собственный переход на личности — это норма. Странно, почему же участники уходят? Наверное, мы недостаточно толерантны к плохим вопросам, это должно быть причиной, что же ещё?

Comment: @VladD мне кажется вы чуть-чуть смешиваете все в одну кучу. Николас представлял интересы SE (и свои). Здесь же речь идет в большой степени о взаимоотношениях с сообществом модераторов и чуть-чуть с SE. Во всяком случае я так эту ситуацию воспринимаю.

Comment: @VladD маховик недоверия сообщества к SE раскручивается. Хоть чатик на зулипе [сюда](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389721/339911) добавляй.

Comment: Зулип ужасно неудобный, может лучше Слэк? Я не в курсе, есть ли сейчас что-то бесплатное и без удаления старых сообщений. Хотя конечно альтчат — это такое знакомое повторение старой истории, надеюсь, что до него не дойдёт.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Я воспринимаю это как более общую проблему: коммуникацию «верхов» и «низов». Те, кто считают себя элитой, должны (по моему мнению) неукоснительно следовать правилам, их самой буквальной букве (точно так же как в реальной жизни судья должен быть кристально, безукоризненно честен). А именно этого и не наблюдается (снова-таки, по моему мнению).

Comment: @AntonMenshov В реальной жизни элиты (часто) нечестны, коррумпированы, стоят выше закона, и мы ничего не можем с этим поделать, приходится жить и смиряться с этим. На SO же все мы добровольцы, и значит, всегда есть вариант _Auf Wierdersehen_.

Answer (score 3):

Меня во всем этом больше удивляет очередная апелляция en-модераторов к тому, что хорошо бы заслужить уважение и всё такое, хотя, по сути, самое важное — доверие сообщества, с которым модератор работает.

Если другие модераторы ставят под сомнение только что выбранного модератора, они, получается, не считаются со всеми теми людьми, что его выбрали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На доверии [такое поведение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12648/12761#comment55426_12753) тоже плохо сказывается. Я бы второй раз за αλεχολυτ вряд ли бы проголосовал после такого.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat во-первых, спасибо за голос. Во-вторых, почему вы верите комментариям непричастных людей, вместо того, чтобы поверить людям причастным? Если не хватает информации, может быть не стоит и судить? Тем более - осуждать. Причина, по которой я отложил подписание соглашения, была мной указана в моём ответе. Так же она была упомянута в TL чате. Разве это моя проблема, что её кто-то не увидел (разумеется из числа тех, кто в принципе имеет доступ к TL чату), а потом начал необоснованно строить теории о том, что я могу слить PII куда-то налево? Как будто я 8 лет только к этому и шёл.

Comment: Даже котик на картинке не помогает. Всё равно минусуют. Как же так!? Люди, что с вами не так!?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Пожалуйста. Я ругаюсь не из-за того комментария (я скинул его потому, что он хорошо описывает мои мысли по этому поводу). Я ругаюсь из-за вашего стиля общения на мета-мете. Вам стоило четко написать, что вы делаете и почему, и что вообще проиошло: сказать, что вы испытываете систему (и что у вас нет несогласия с подписанием модсоглашения); сказать, подписано ли сейчас соглашение, и было ли оно подписано на момент отбирания у вас доступов, и т.п. Когда я вас там прямо спросил, что вы делаете, вы не ответили.

Comment: Вы писали, что человек, отобравший у вас доступ, не мог проверить статус подписания соглашения. Но как вы это определили - не написали.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вы сейчас про какой вопрос говорите? где именно я должен был четко написать про испытывание системы?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ну как минимум [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388702/how-can-i-ask-a-question-regarding-moderator-related-issues-if-i-dont-have-acce). Написано очень заковыристо. Я так понимаю, идея была задать вопрос в общем виде, и это может даже и хорошо, но тогда стоило добавить приписку, объясняющую, зачем вы это спрашиваете (так и так, испытывал систему, у меня отобрали доступ по такой-то причине, не пойму,  куда теперь писать). Иначе такая скрытность вызывает непонимание и недовольство.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вы правильно поняли идею, я хотел как раз задать вопрос в общем виде, без специфики и истории. Как это и принято делать в вопросах на SE - минимально и достаточно. Без лишнего шума. Нужно решение [support], а не обсуждение [discussion]. Большинство, давших ответы, смогли достаточно лаконично их оформить. Но самым заплюсованным (на моё удивление) оказался ответ с "перемыванием косточек" и переходом на личность вопрошающего. Сейчас этим моментом занимается "Trust & Safety team", очень интересно услышать их резолюцию, но пока ответ висит как и был в прежнем виде.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat по поводу проверки статуса подписания соглашения и лишения доступа я писал в своём [ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12753/176217). Статус подписания видят другие модераторы ТОГО ЖЕ сайта, модераторы с других сайтов не могут никак знать статус подписания соглашения. И, конечно же, сотрудники компании должны иметь доступ к статусу подписания, особенно если они выдают/блокируют доступ к ModTeams.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ *"я писал в своём ответе"* Это бы в оригинальный вопрос. :/ *"без специфики и истории. Как это и принято делать в вопросах на SE"* Ну, не всегда принято. Отсутствие истории иногда критикуют как проблему XY.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ В любом случае, если такой стиль общения не зашёл обитателям мета-меты, в следующий раз я бы попробовал что-то другое.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat у нас разные миры в MSE и ruSO. Английский не мой родной язык. Разные культуры. Это всё вносит определённую долю непринятия. Как с одной, так и с другой стороны.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat кстати, ещё момент по поводу "подписано ли соглашение" - посмотрите внимательно на второй абзац обсуждаемого [вопроса](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388702/339911). Можно ли сделать из этого какой-то вывод?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Угу, на чужом языке сложнее передать правильную эмоцию. *"сделать из этого какой-то вывод"* Что-то не понял.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat абзац подразумевает, что соглашение подписано.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Уф. Ну теоретически да, хотя с другой стороны вы могли беспокоиться и за нарушение еще не подписанного соглашения.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну да, додумывать можно в разные стороны. В какой-то стороне работает "assume good intent", в какой-то не очень.